# setTintColor: doesn't redraw UIImageView immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIImageView` in `UICollectionViewCell`, and the image on `UIImageView` uses `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` render mode.

When I click the cell I will change the `tintColor` of `UImageView`, but I found the `UIImageView` doesn't **redraw immediately**. However when I clicked a second cell, the **first** one did render with its `tintColor` while the **second** one didn't.

And in **Reveal** and **LLDB**, I found the `tintColor` is set **correctly**.

If I set `tintColor` **manually** in **LLDB**, It can show **correctly**.

[image]
.
[image]
.
[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance doing the `tintColor` setting in a secondary thread? This sounds like an issue where you might be updating the UI in a thread which is not the main thread ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dispatch your screen manipulating code to the main queue:

**Obj-C:**

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // The tint here
  });
```

**Swift 3:**

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // The tint here
 }
```